# Persist HTML5 data attributes in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, polymer

I've got an idea for a simple app. It presents a number of questions that the user must answer and it will store the answers for these questions for local use. Because there's no reason for the data to be online, I'll use local storage, so the app can also work offline. I believe I should use the HTML5 local storage for that.

The obvious approach is to use a dataset that I setup in Javascript, and store it's serialized copy. But since the structure of the data that I want to store is completely aligned with the structure of the HTML (DOM), I was wondering if it would make sense to store the data inside the HTML (DOM), using HTML5 data attributes. That way I spare some Javascript code for setting up and synchronizing a parallell data structure in code.

My question: is there an elegant way to persist the current state of the HTML, including it's data-attributes, so that when the app is closed and started again, the previous state of the data attributes can be restored? Should I serialize the DOM in some way and store it? And what about deserialization and restoring it? Or is this whole concept bad practice?

Regards,
Vic

PS. can Web Components (cf. Polymer) offer something in this direction? It seems to me that what I'm looking for is real semantic HTML, not?

Comment: Store JSON in local storage, then load that into an object that has a 'render' method, that can put the right things in the right place. If you do it nicely, the id of the inputs could match the keys in the JSON, which will make it easy. You can then use object.observe to ensure it's always up to date.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in this document: http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/

- you can use localStorage: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage to store the data.
- you can provide a cache manifest for the app to work offline.

I recommend the TODOMVC website which has many examples for localStorage. e.g. http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/#/